# What is a move mount and how is it different from a bind mount?

Tags: mount, bind-mount

I've been using `bind` mounts for 20 years, they're pretty simple. Now I see there is also a `move` mount,

> The move operation
>
> Move a mounted tree to another place (atomically).  The call is:
>
> ```
> mount --move olddir newdir
> ```
>
> **This  will  cause the contents which previously appeared under `olddir` to now be accessible under `newdir`.  The physical location of the files is not changed.**

Sounds like a bind mount to me. What's the difference between this and binding the newdir to the olddir?

Comment: Seems to me that `bind` is like `cp` for mount point, and `move` is like `mv`.

Comment: With a bind mount p->q both p & q are accessible showing the same contents. With a move mount p->q the contents are no longer accessible through p. For one...